# MD5 and Base64 encoding mismatch in R and Java/JavaScript

Tags: r

I am trying to encode in base64 a string that was calculated from MD5 function in R. But the result seems to be different than what I am getting Scala/Java/JavaScript:

Scala/Java/JavaScript for an empty string is giving as a result: **1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==**

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

object Test extends  App {

  val empty = ""
  val md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(empty.getBytes("UTF-8"))

  val base64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(md5))
  println(base64)

  //Result: 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==

}
```

Similarly, in JavaScript, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-md5

```
md5.base64(''); // 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
```

But in R, I am getting a different result: **ZDQxZDhjZDk4ZjAwYjIwNGU5ODAwOTk4ZWNmODQyN2U=**

```
> library(digest)
> md5 <- digest("", algo="md5", serialize=F)
> md5 [1] "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
> base64encode(md5) [1] "ZDQxZDhjZDk4ZjAwYjIwNGU5ODAwOTk4ZWNmODQyN2U="
```

I am wondering if md5 does not encode in hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the digest, just ask for the raw vector and base64 encode that (add `raw=TRUE`).

```
library(digest)
md5 <- digest("", algo="md5", serialize=FALSE, raw=TRUE)
openssl::base64_encode(md5)
# [1] "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg=="
```

Answer (score 2):

In your examples the base64 encoding is applied to different objects:

- in R you encode the hex digest, i.e., a string ("d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e")
- in Scala you obtain an Array of Bytes from MD5

In your Scala code

```
scala> val md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(empty.getBytes("UTF-8"))
md5: Array[Byte] = Array(-44, 29, -116, -39, -113, 0, -78, 4, -23, -128, 9, -104, -20, -8, 66, 126)
```

The MD5 hex digest in Scala is the same as in R:

```
scala> md5.map(v => f"$v%02x").mkString
res0: String = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to get this "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==" in R. How can I do it? should I convert "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" to hex?

Comment: Is there a way to get an array of bytes like in scala? what I want is just to get the same output with R

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate the Scala/Java/JS output in R, convert your string to a raw array. This requires a fair amount of string mangling:

```
x <- openssl::md5("")
m <- matrix(strsplit(x, "")[[1]], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
s <- strtoi(paste0(m[, 1], m[, 2]), 16)
openssl::base64_encode(as.raw(s))
# [1] "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg=="
```